# equation inside frame in beamer causes error - Missing $ inserted

Tags: beamer, equations, arrays

I do not find the error that latex shows, this is my code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[figurename=Fig]{caption}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
\dot{X}_1&=\dot{v}_c(t)\\
\dot{X}_2 & = -\frac{1}{LC}X_1- \frac{R}{L}X_2+v_i(t)\\
\end{align}
Ahora escribimos las ecuaciónes de forma matricial:
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
\dot{X}_1\\
\dot{X}_2
\end{array}\right] 

\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-1\frac{1}{LC} & -\frac{R}{L}
\end{array}\right] 

\left[\begin{array}{c}
X_1\\
X_2
\end{array}\right]+  

\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\frac{1}{LC}
\end{array}\right] v_i(t)
\end{equation}•
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You see how I improved the title. The title must contain the basic information and should lead people with similar problems to your post if they google it.

Comment: Why was this down voted exactly? Why did the down-voter not leave a comment? (Unless it was @MaestroGlanz. But people don't usually down vote if they plan to improve a question since they'd just need to un-down vote it once they improved it.)

Comment: @cfr I did un-down. There has been a mysterious other user. It may refer to the original title.

Comment: But that's my point: the down-voter should leave a comment. @MaestroGlanz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not have blank lines in `equation` delete the three blank lines and the error will go.

Comment: You were faster.